# How to increment value dyanamically through forloop

Tags: php

I am working as php developer, I want to keep one select box field with full or price. I want to start price from 10000 and end with 15000000. I want increace my value like (10000,20000,30000....) for this i have tried,

```
<?php
$minsale = 10000;
$maxsale = 15000000;
?>
<select class="form-control" name="min" id="minval">
    <?php for($sal = $minsale; $sal <= $maxsale; $sal++) {
        $sal = $sal + 10000;
    ?>
        <option <?php echo (isset($_GET['min']) && $_GET['min'] == $sal) ? 'selected=selected' : ''; ?>value="<?php echo $sal; ?>"></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

For this i am getting (20000,30001,40002...). 
How to solve this, can any one please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incrementing it twice. Once in the for loop ($sal++), and again at the beginning of the loop. If you want to just increment it by 10000, put it in the loop conditions.

```
<?php for($sal = $minsale; $sal <= $maxsale; $sal+=10000) {
?>
```

To be able to change the increments use a variable that you can change later:

```
<?php 
  $inc = 100000;
  for($sal = $minsale; $sal <= $maxsale; $sal+=$inc) {

      if($sal >= 100000) { // set this to whatever number you want
          $inc = 25000;
      }
?>
```

Comment: After reached certain amount, i want to increment it by 25000, for this how to proceed